# Android history stack - going back more than one step

Tags: android, back-stack, android-navigation

Here's the scenario:

1. In activity `A` I have "post to Twitter" option which calls activity `B` that executes the post and returns to `A` by executing `Activity#finish()` and the flow is `A->B->A`
2. However, if I'm not logged into Twitter then the `B` activity calls Twitter mobile OAuth page in the browser. Then browser redirects user back to `B`. However when `B` is done and I call `Activity#finish()` I'm returning back to the browser login page which is expected since the stack is now `A->B->browser->B`.

How do I go 3 steps back instead of just one? Is it even possible? I don't want to call `A` anew since at the very least I will lose a list position

Comment: Can you post the code for `B->browser`?

Comment: Pretty standard: `final Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)); activity.startActivity(intent);`

Comment: Why don't you call `finish()` on B as soon as you fire the browser intent? That way when you return from the Browser, the next activity in the stack would be A.

Comment: @Aki, alas this won't work since browser is not simply returning to B but calls it anew so there's 2 instances of B in the stack. What you propose will shorten path to A->browser->B but doing finish() from B will still return to the browser

Comment: How does the browser redirect user back to B? It is the standard android browser you are opening, right? How can it know which activity to invoke?

Comment: @Aki you should read something about OAuth processing but in short - browser is provided with "callback URL". As far as answer to my question please read post from smith324

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with [FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP) and [FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP).

You need to launch A as a new Intent but set those two flags before calling `startActivity`

Clear Top causes all activities on top of A to get cleared away.

Single Top causes the intent to be delivered to A's `onNewIntent` method instead of destroying and recreating A.

From the docs:

> If set, and the activity being launched is already running in the current task, then instead of launching a new instance of that activity, all of the other activities on top of it will be closed and this Intent will be delivered to the (now on top) old activity as a new Intent.
>   For example, consider a task consisting of the activities: A, B, C, D. If D calls startActivity() with an Intent that resolves to the component of activity B, then C and D will be finished and B receive the given Intent, resulting in the stack now being: A, B.
>   The currently running instance of activity B in the above example will either receive the new intent you are starting here in its onNewIntent() method, or be itself finished and restarted with the new intent. If it has declared its launch mode to be "multiple" (the default) and you have not set FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP in the same intent, then it will be finished and re-created; for all other launch modes or if FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP is set then this Intent will be delivered to the current instance's onNewIntent().
>   This launch mode can also be used to good effect in conjunction with FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK: if used to start the root activity of a task, it will bring any currently running instance of that task to the foreground, and then clear it to its root state. This is especially useful, for example, when launching an activity from the notification manager.
>   See Tasks and Back Stack for more information about tasks.

Comment: This sounds very plausible, I will try and accept the answer based on results

Comment: Unfortunately in my particular case this solution does not work. I think that is due to the fact that browser doesn't call `startActivity` but instead int broadcasts the intent with filter and that somehow breaks the chain. So when I do B.finish() I'm still going back to the browser

Comment: If the browser is started with the NEW TASK flag then it break the 'flow' so to speak.  Tasks are a complicated subject and this just about hits the limit of my understanding.  One approach you might consider is SINGLE TASK (I *think* it might help you but am not 100%. Single task forces your application to forego the usual multiple task lifestyle of Android apps) You can always read more about them here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/tasks-and-back-stack.html

Comment: Since I don't think there is (or should be) another way to monkey with history stack other than using various flags I'm going to accept this answer. Thanks @smith324!